How to set FilterChip color?
Is there a way to set the containerColor of the FilterChip so that it remains the same regardless of the elevation value?
I'm trying to add a shadow to the FilterChip, and the only method that yields a decent result is setting the elevation. However, when I set the elevation, the color gets tinted.
I also tried using Modifier.shadow(), .clip(CircleShape), and .background(), but this approach leaves empty space between the chip and the shadow.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Welcome to stackoverflow! If you found an answer useful, please mark it as accepted answer by clicking the checkmark at the left side of the answer. Thank you!

If you want to add elevation to your FilterChip, you should use an ElevatedFilterChip instead:
ElevatedFilterChip(
    modifier = Modifier,
    elevation = FilterChipDefaults.elevatedFilterChipElevation(elevation = 8.dp),
    selected = false,
    onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
    label = {
        Text(text = "FilterChip")
    }
)

With this, the color will not change, no matter which elevation you set.
Output:

